# Devise 1.5.3 and Flash Message Presentation?

Tags: devise, activeadmin, devise-confirmable

If you are using registerable and confirmable, why is it that you only get registerable styled flash messages?

Active Admin has munged my il8n config, and won't display my devise.en.yml file.

I just want my people to know they are getting an email. The same message that confirmable would deliver, but is some only the registerable is shown.

I tried putting confirmable ahead of registerable in my model, but that didn't change anything.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that you need to prepend the `devise.en.yml` file with things like:

```
    registrations:
      user:
        signed_up: 'Welcome friend! You have signed up successfully.'
        inactive_signed_up: 'Yo! You done signed up. Please Check your email and click the confirmation link to continue.'
```

Prior to finding this out, I did not prepend with `user:`, since we have `admin:` too thanks to active admin. adding `user:` was the key.

Hopefully google will find this for people trying to change the devise en.yml file and it not taking effect.